# SharePoint 2010 Designer workflow throwing error

Tags: designer-workflow

I have created a SharePoint 2010 Designer workflow which sends an email to a user when an item is created and it has approval and decline if approved it will go back to the initiator but am facing a weird error here when the Initiator creates the item it is not sending emails the error shows the following

> "The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more
>   columns for the item require a different type of information"

Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: You may need to provide more detail on the workflow - what it updates/creates and the columns in your list.  The error is usually spot on - you are trying to put data of one type into a column that expects something else.

Comment: Hi Jesus Shelby i have a task list with columns employee name, comments, created by , approval status and title. when a user creates new item in the list it sends a email to a group which is happening once the item is created it sends a approval email and the approver opens it from email and hits approve it should send email to the user who created the item.but once the approver hit approve no emails are being sent and the error shows as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added a column  to the list called status as choice yes/no depending on status I am sending the mails now. But could not rectify what is the issue on the error I am getting. I have tried several options provided in different sources from google but could not solve this except adding the new column did the job for me.Thanks.